# What is a Baby Gap?

Tags: meaning

In "You've Got Mail", Kathleen reflecting on her closing store: "It's a lovely store, and in a week it will be something really depressing, like a Baby Gap." Is a Baby Gap some kind of character?

Comment: If this winds up being closed, you can post it at https://movies.stackexchange.com/ which specializes in questions about movies and television.

Answer (score 8):

The Gap is a well-known chain of clothing stores. The stores focus on casual and athletic clothing. The customers are mainly teenagers and young adults. A Baby Gap is a clothing store in the Gap chain which sells clothing for children under about two years of age.

Gap stores can be found in most any American city. Since they are chain stores they all look about the same and carry mostly the same goods. The employees in American chain stores are there to set out the goods and to collect payment from the customers. They are seldom expected to take an interest in what they are selling or to advise customers on what to buy.

Kathleen runs an independent bookstore. Because it is not part of a chain its appearance and the selection of books sold there reflect her tastes and the tastes of her customers. She and her employees are almost certainly people who love books. Employees in independent bookstores tend to know a lot about the books they sell and regularly advise customers on what to buy.

She is thinking about what might happen to the space her bookstore occupies if it closes. It might be rented to someone who will open a small chain store such as a Baby Gap. This would make her sad. It might make her neighbors sad too. Every time a store with local character is replaced with a chain store, the neighborhood becomes more like thousands of other neighborhoods in America and a little less interesting.

Answer (score 5):

Gap is a clothing retailer. While most of their stores are just called “Gap” they also have some more specialized stores under that label, one of which is [babyGap](https://www.gap.com/browse/division.do?cid=1137869), which sells clothing for babies.